# Optimizing Codeigniter Queries

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a table with at least 650,000 records, and will go up to 15M+ records. I just wonder why it takes roughly 8-14 seconds to load some of the pages especially when searching and when pointing the `page_id(pagination)` to the last pages, considering the query is quite limited.

Model:

```
function fetch_persons($limit, $id, $search, $district = null, $city = null) {

        if($search) {
            $this->db->group_start();
            $this->db->like('persons.fullname', $search, 'after');
            $this->db->group_end();                
        }


        if(!is_null($district)) {
            $this->db->where('persons.district_code', $district);
        }
        if(!is_null($city)) {
            $this->db->where('persons.city_code', $city);
        }
        if(!is_null($barangay)) {
            $this->db->where('persons.brgy_code', $barangay);
        }

         $this->db->select('
            persons.id,
            persons.fullname,
            persons.address,
            persons.sex,                
            persons.deceased,   
            city.name as city,          
            district.name as district,                  
          ');        

        $this->db->join('city', 'city.code = persons.city_code', 'left');
        $this->db->join('district', 'district.code = persons.district_code', 'left');
        $this->db->limit($limit, (($id-1)*$limit));
        $this->db->order_by('persons.id', 'ASC');

        $query = $this->db->get("persons");

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $query->result_array();
        }
        return false;

}
```

I tried `$this->db->cache_on();` but it's no good for me.

When doing a `search` or `LIKE` does all data gets processed? 
As well as `limit 100, 6000`?

What are the ways to better optimize the queries?

What are the alternative solutions?

Comment: I doubt it's an issue with your queries specifically (but I could be wrong), but rather an inefficiency in your actual database setup.

Comment: Do your database tables contain any indices on the fields you're searching or joining on? How much of a difference does it make if you disable one or more of the search conditions?

Comment: Addressing the `LIMIT` question, using `LIMIT` does not reduce processing time as all the work needed to build the resultset will be done before outputting it, which is when `LIMIT` usually comes in: it limits the amount of data that gets transferred. This is not a codeigniter issue but a MySQL one. You're most likely making one or more full scans due to lack or misuse of indexes. Without seeing your table structures it's hard to pinpoint the culprits, but running an `EXPLAIN` on the queries will shed some light on the next steps

Comment: at first - put an explain before your query and check the usage of indices - after that update your question with those informations and include your table structure and your indices - its pretty much impossbile to answer a question like this with so little information...

Comment: Please add the indexing on the primary fields and on the which you use it in the where clause. Also please privide your table structure so we provide better vision on it.

Comment: I tried changing the Engine to InnoDB and it seemed to be much more faster, than the recent, MyISAM. With InnoDB, query results at 2sec.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try indexing your database? If you didn't that should save about 80% of page loading time.